# Unexpected behaviour of position relative on body

Tags: html, css, specifications

So, let's say we have the following code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    /* position: relative; */
}

.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 100px;
    background: gray;
}

.absolute {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

In this case the `.absolute` element is positioned relative to the body, as expected.

Not let's add `position: relative` to the body.
The element is now positioned relative to the `.container`. Which doesn't make sense, as [absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) which is body in this case.

Is body positioning treated differently from other elements?

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Futurial/pen/vxdxxg?editors=1100)

Comment: Removing `top: 10px` also has the same result as it snaps to the `container` as well, regardless of `body` position.

Comment: In the default situation, `position:absolute` elements are positioned relatively to the canvas, not the body. So there is a difference between the default and giving the body a position. Now as to the problem, well, that's the old collapsing margins issue. Giving the first child of a block element a margin causes the block itself to have that margin too. So the problem will disappear if you don't give the .container a margin.

Comment: Thank you @MrLister. The collapsed margin threw off my intuition. And I didn't even think about checking the body with dev tools. I guess next time better sleep on it before posting on stackoverflow. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the specification about [absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned):

> The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor (or, if none exists, the [initial containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details), as in our example).

Ok, you have none nearest positioned ancestors, move along to the [initial containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details):

> The position and size of an element's box(es) are sometimes calculated relative to a certain rectangle, called the *containing block* of the element. The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> 1. The containing block in which the [root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#root) lives is a rectangle called the *initial containing block*. For continuous media, it has the dimensions of the [viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#viewport) and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is the [page area](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-area) for paged media.

Good, and what is the [root element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-root-element) in your case:

> The [html](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) element [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) the root of an HTML document.

It means that by default your the `.absolute` element is positioned **not relative** to the `<body>`, but to the `<html>`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you do not specify the position: relative, then the elements will have a position of :static ( https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp ). You actually need to insert position relative to the .container element if you want to place .absolute depending on the container element. This is why you have the strange behavior.